# Postman throw SSL Error: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames - AWS EB

Tags: postman, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have setup SSL for AWS EB whcih terminates at ALB. It works when I do

```
CURL https://sampleapp.xxx-wedxxx.us-east-x.elasticbeanstalk.com/score/33639237
```

In VSCode extension - thunderclient

```
GET https://sampleapp.xxx-wedxxx.us-east-x.elasticbeanstalk.com/score/33639237
```

But, in postman it throws above error. I went throw the stackoverflow answer which suggest add host header as public Instance but As I am using EB with auto scaling, the instance can change and switching off SSL verification doesn't sounds like a good option to me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Error is pretty clear. What entries does your cert have for alt names? For a few years now certes require this field even with a single name on the cert. CN is no longer used.

Comment: I have altnames say mysite.xyz and I have record A mysite.xyz to sampleapp.xxx-wedxxx.us-east-x.elasticbeanstalk.com too.

Comment: But you aren’t connecting to mysite.xyz are you?

Comment: I'm not connecting to https://mysite.xyz becuase it's not working. throws error like - Couldn't resolve the hostname to an IP address